# PDF to Apple Newsstand

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf

What is the best way to go about adding a monthly subscription to the Apple Newsstand?

I am currently working with a site which deals with PDF subscriptions through Ubercart and we are now looking to support iPads through the Apple Newsstand. We would like pay as you go and full yearly subscriptions which would allow the user to download any previous issues for free.

How much work would this be? Do you need to make a bespoke app to do this or is there a straight forward way to do it?

The PDF would ideally show just as it is, we don't currently have any need to integrate rich media into it such as some of the more popular subscriptions out there currently do.

Comment: Plus 1 for good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the video from the apple developer site explaining all about how the newsstand works. [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaXZNTTtgIM)

You should be able to find all your answers there.

Answer (score 3):

This is the best tutorial for the News Stand app

Here is the Link :

http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/